# What is a self-contained cross-platform encryption for USB drive?

Tags: windows, linux, disk-encryption, macos, usb-drive

I'm trying to find self-contained encryption solution for USB drives while at the same time being platform independent. For example, Windows' BitLocker only works on Windows and not on OS X or Linux.

If I'm going to use TrueCrypt to encrypt the drive, it will need to be installed on the host computer somehow. (On OSX at least.)

As such, I'm looking for some solution that will reside within the USB itself and will work on the 3 major operating systems out of the box (no additional drivers to download, etc).

Comment: Sounds like you want an [IronKey](http://www.ironkey.com/).  Mine works on Windows and Linux (and I'll bet it works on Mac), and it has an unencrypted partition for tools used to mount the encrypted partition.

Comment: IronKey looks nice, but I'm looking for something to use on USB drives I already own.